# Android: How to pass String variable to Dialog Options Menu

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I have a ListView which is display several String and a method of setOnItemLongClick which will call and pop out a dialog options menu which has the options of Add, View and Delete. The setOnItemLongCLick will be triggered when the user LongClick one of the item from the Listview such as "Dictionary", "Book" or "Journal".

What I want to do here is, after the user has long pressed "Journal" and choose delete option, I want to Toast message "Delete Journal". If "Book" has been long pressed so it will be "Delete Book" and so on. So I need to get the String selected from setOnItemLongClick and pass the String into the Dialog Options Menu.

I'm wonder if this is possible and how? Thanks in advance for your help.

This is my code for Set Dialog Menu Options

```
   final String[] option = new String[] { "Add", "View", "Delete" }; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    builder.setTitle("Select Option"); 
    builder.setAdapter(adapter2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        { // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            switch(which){
            case 0: 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1: 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2: 
                String delete="";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Delete " + delete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                // nothing
                break;
            }
        } 

    });

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

This is my code for Set On Item Long Click

```
    mylist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            //show dialog menu options box

            dialog.show(); 
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of calling  `dialog.show();`  on `onItemLongClick` you can wrap all dialog related code in an method with an selected index parameter to get pressed item position in Dialog box as:

```
private AlertDialog showOpetionMenu(int selected_index){

  // your code here...

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

return dialog;
}
```

and on `onItemLongClick` you can get dialog instance by passing selected index :

```
 @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                                        int arg2, long arg3) 
      {
         //show dialog menu options box
         AlertDialog dialog=dialogshowOpetionMenu(arg2);//<<pass selected index
         dialog.show(); 
         return true;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Your answer is a great help

Comment: @FitriIzuan : but my answer is same as posted by you. so can i k why you unaccept ?

Comment: Sorry sir, I did accept your answer. Furthermore, my answer is also from your answer. And I didn't know the acceptable answer can only be one while I want to accept both of the answers. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onItemLongClic`k you can use `public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, final View v, final ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)` where you setup the options for edit and delete or whatever you need to.

The actions for the item selected from the context menu can be processed in

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item)
```

For more information on context menu see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html).

For a step by step tutorial visit [here](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/).

[Here](http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/01/context-menus-example-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

After the help given by several people, this is what I got.

create a method for AlertDIalog:

```
    private AlertDialog showOpetionMenu(final String selected_index){

    final String[] option = new String[] { "Add", "View", "Delete" }; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    builder.setTitle("Select Option"); 
    builder.setAdapter(adapter2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        { // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            switch(which){
            case 0: 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1: 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2: 
                delete="";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Delete" + selected_index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                // nothing
                break;
            }
        } 

    }); 

    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); 

    return dialog;
    }
```

Then just do this in onItemLongClick

```
    mylist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            //show dialog menu options box
            String selectedType=listType.get(arg2);
            AlertDialog dialog=showOpetionMenu(selectedType);//<<pass selected index
            dialog.show(); 
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Thank you very much for helping me!